# How to diagnose package dependancies?

Tags: apt, dependencies

I want to install `postfixadmin` on trusty. I'm confused about dependencies.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/postfixadmin shows (I think) that it needs apache2 OR lighttpd OR the  httpd to be installed.

I have already installed `nginx-full`, which, I believe should satisfy `httpd` and therefore apt should NOT need to install `apache`.

But `apt-get -s install postfixadmin` wants to install `apache2`, and I don't understand why?

Any ideas?

Comment: try with `apt-cache depends <package-name>`

Answer (score 1):

One of the dependencies of `postfixadmin` is `libapache2-mod-php5 | php5-cgi | php5`. `libapache2-mod-php5` depends on `apache2`, as you might expect. `php5` depends on `libapache2-mod-php5`. `php5-cgi`, on the other hand, does *not* depend on anything Apache.

Therefore, if you install `php5-cgi` first and then install `postfixadmin`, Apache won't be installed.